# iphone UIView - Get notified when view has loaded?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, delegates

I have a subclass of UIView, I want to be notified as soon as the view is loaded on the screen.
Is there some kind of delegate method for a UIView.

---

**NOTE:** I am not using a UIViewController

Comment: How are you displaying your view?

Comment: In main window I init it and then add it to my window as a subview

Comment: Then you know exactly when it appears on screen. It's when you do that.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no delegate method but you can override,

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using OpenGL, you could use the *- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect* for that.

Answer (score -2):

Set the class which opens your view as the delegate of the view, then on viewDidLoad (which runs as soon as the view is opened, even if it's not by a viewController per se) notify the delegate. That should work, I believe.